# Can I use a smaller bike inner tube than it supposed to

Tags: tire

My bike says I need a size 29" inner tube and I got a 26" wheel what’s gonna happen?

Comment: Let me get 100% sure - are you asking what would happen if you put a 26 inch inner tube on a 29 inch wheel?

Comment: Ya think my friends dyslexic and I don’t feel like hiking back to the shop

Comment: What's gonna happen is the inner tube goes "bang" and you hike back to a shop. Better to do it now.

Answer (score 3):

That's not going to work, you need an inner tube of the proper size for your wheel rim diameter *and* tire width.

The tire width should be printed on the tire along with the diameter. Tubes come in various width sizes that support a range of tire widths.

If in doubt, take the bike or wheel to the bike shop and let the staff pick a compatible tube for you.

Comment: Some tubes will also fit a range of rim diameters. A tube fitting both 27" and 700c (630mm and 622mm), for example. But not 26" and 29".

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to get the tube to physically fit. However when the tube is inflated it will be stretched so thin it will be seriously compromised. It will likely burst if punctured or impacted.